# Animating to an array

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, arduino

I have an Arduino, and I am trying to find the most efficient way to animate pixels in an array. The array is represented by 3 arrays of 30 `uint8_t`s. (30 pixels * R+G+B levels 0-255).

What is the best way to move pixels down the array independently? This is a memory limited environment (2 KB RAM), and the array takes up 720 bytes. I had originally tried to use an array for each pixel, and ran out of memory. A second implementation used if statements, and it works well, but it is very tedious to make new patterns. I am looking for a way to solve the problem that may be better than how I am solving it now.

Here's an example of a pattern I would like to animate.

```
X moves forward 1 each cycle.
Y moves forward 3 places then back 2.
Z moves backwards 3 places each cycle.

|_|X|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|Y|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|Z|
|_|_|X|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|Y|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|Z|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|X|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|Y|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|Z|_|_|_|_|_|_|
```

And here's the code I would use.

```
void animateScene1() {
    for(int i = 0; i <= numPixels; i++) {
        setColor(i, X);
        if(i < 15) {
            if(i % 2 == 0)
                setColor((i+15)+3), Y);
            else
                setColor((i+15)-2), Y);
        }
        if(i < 10)
            setColor(numPixels-3*i, Z);
    }
}
```

Any ideas of better ways?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  You want general-purpose code to perform specific animations?

Comment: Exactly. So rather than creating a function to code each specific animation, if I could say X is a vector of magnitude 1, Z is a vector of magnitude -3, and be able to simplify the creation of additional patterns

Comment: Then the only thing I can suggest is to collate a list of parameters you'd like to use for your animations (e.g. number of steps per cycle, number of cycles before it stops, direction, etc.), and then implement them one by one.  Then you can specify your animations simply as a list of parameters.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I don't know how to implement that in code. Could you share a little of what you are thinking in code? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a function like this?

```
int pixelAt(int index, int min, int max, int a, int b, int b_2)
{
    int pixel = -1;

    if (min <= index && index <= max)
    {
        pixel = a * index + b;
        if (i % 2)
        {
            pixel += b_2;
        }
    }

    return pixel;
}
```

Then you would have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numPixels; i++)
{
    // This assumes setColor(-1, x) does nothing
    setColor(pixelAt(i, 0, numPixels, 1, 0, 0), X);
    setColor(pixelAt(i, 0, 15, 1, 18, -5), Y);
    setColor(pixelAt(i, 0, 10, -3, numPixels, 0), Z);
}
```

Of course, the `pixelAt` function will get much more complicated if you add new requirements, such as changing the multiplication factor for even numbers, treating multiples of 3 differently, etc.  However, you could use functions similar to this one to reduce the number of functions you have to write.  One for simple patterns, one for even/odd patterns, one for multiples of threes, and so on.  Depends on how different the patterns are, and how much memory space you have for code.

Comment: This is great! I was having a mental block as to how I could make it work.